# Prove that $\log_52$ is irrational

Tags: elementary-number-theory, logarithms, rationality-testing

> Prove that $\log_5(2) \in \mathbb{R}\setminus \mathbb{Q}$ (irrational numbers).

I know there is a question out there already for this but my problem is that I need to prove this using the fundamental theorem of arithmetic. I'm not too good with proving via this method and so would appreciate clarification and help.
What I have so far:
Suppose by way of contradiction that $\log_5 (2)$ is rational,
then it can be written as $\log_5 (2)= m/n$ for some $m$,$n$ that are integers
Then $5^{m/n} = 2$ which is equivalent to $5^m = 2^n$. Now I'm stuck here. Where does the fundamental theorem of arithmetic come in and how can I use it to show that $5^m = 2^n$ cannot be true?

Comment: Please state what you know of the fundamental theorem of arithmetic.

Answer (score 2):

The fundamental theorem of arithmetic tells you that $5^m$ and $2^n$ each have a unique prime factorization, which you have displayed.  If they were equal, you would have one number with two factorizations.

Answer (score 0):

The fundamental theorem of arithmetics is that every number can be uniquely written as the product of prime factors.

Now, $2^n$ and $5^m$ can be uniquely written as product of factors; hence, the representations:

$$2^n = 2 \times 2 \times \cdots \times 2$$

$$5^m = 5 \times 5 \times \cdots \times 5$$

$n$ times and $m$ times respectively, are unique.

What is the conclusion?

Comment: If they were equal, their prime factorizations would look the same?

Comment: @SamZa Yes.  But it is worthwhile to note the subtlety that if $m=n=0$ then these factorings are indeed the same.  Your logic should not be overly dependent on whether they "look" the same, but focus more precisely on their differences.

Answer (score 0):

$$\log_5 (2)= m/n\implies m,n\ne 0 $$ and WLOG $m,n\gt 0$ 
But $5^m$ is always odd while $2^n$ is always even so they can not be equal.